# extracting exact number of rows from a list

Tags: r

A list of numbers like

```
a
1
2
3 
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
15
16
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
```

To extract 3 continuous values without duplicates. 
Result should be like

It is like making every 3 continuous rows to column but we can see 7,8,9 are also continuous but neglected to remove duplicates

```
a   b   c
1   2   3
6   7   8
9  10  11
19 20  21
22 23  24
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: actual data is quiet big

Comment: Okay, I didn't look at your second logic.  Do you have lengths different for each continous sequence or is it always 3?

Comment: i need always 3 continuous, coming without duplicates

Comment: ok i will make a list from this

Comment: I meant if it was of idfferent lengths, now this looks fine.

Comment: I would say that your example is a bit confusing as 19:24 is a single sequence, so you convert that to 2 sequence of 3, but suppose if it was 19:23 or 19:22, what will be output?

Comment: then it will take 19 20 21 only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit untidy, but does the job:

```
d <- data.frame(a=a[-(1:2)], diff=diff(a, 2))
d$br <- 0
for (i in 1:nrow(d)) {
  if (i==1 & d$diff[1]==2) {
    d$br[1] <- 1
  } else if (i==2 & d$diff[2]==2 & d$br[1]!=1) {
    d$br[2] <- 1
  }
  if (d$diff[i]==2 & !any(sum(d$br[c(i-1, i-2)])>0)) d$br[i] <- 1
}
t(sapply(d$a[d$br==1], function(x) (x-2):x))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    3
# [2,]    6    7    8
# [3,]    9   10   11
# [4,]   19   20   21
# [5,]   22   23   24
```

Wrapping all that into a function, and testing with another sequence:

```
getConsec <- function(a) {
    d <- data.frame(a=a[-(1:2)], diff=diff(a, 2))
    d$br <- 0
    for (i in 1:nrow(d)) {
      if (i==1 & d$diff[1]==2) {
        d$br[1] <- 1
      } else if (i==2 & d$diff[2]==2 & d$br[1]!=1) {
        d$br[2] <- 1
      }
      if (d$diff[i]==2 & !any(sum(d$br[c(i-1, i-2)])>0)) d$br[i] <- 1
    }
    t(sapply(d$a[d$br==1], function(x) (x-2):x))
}

a <- sort(sample(1:30, 20))
 # [1]  1  2  3  4  6 10 12 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 23 25 27 28 30
getConsec(a)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    3
# [2,]   14   15   16
# [3,]   17   18   19
```

Comment: getConsec function is not available, can you tell me d pckage

Comment: `getConsec` is exactly the function that I described above.  I edited my answer to make that clear.

Comment: ok i will try this on a bigger data set now

Comment: thank you sir,
 one more issue i have,
i want to replicate this function to get 60 consecutive values, 
where should i edit as i am new to r code

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this should get the job done

```
matrix(unique(a),ncol=3, byrow=T)
```

It will disregard the duplicate values and then fill a 3 column matrix by row with them

Comment: no, its pasting all elements to 3 columns

Comment: But thats what your example does?!

Comment: no, your method is pasting all elements not the required ones

Comment: from your code results are like 
1 2 3 
6 7 8 
9 10 11
12 15 16

it is not continuous

Comment: so you want only sequences in the rows? so 12 15 16 wouldnt be there?